# Как передать данные скопированого текста в мое поле на моем сайте?

Tags: javascript

Я создал букмарклет, который при нажатии ищет в google выделенный мною текст.
Это выглядит вот так :

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){ var selected; if (window.getSelection) selected = window.getSelection(); else if (document.getSelection) selected = document.getSelection(); else selected = document.selection.createRange().text; var q = ''+selected; if (q) location='http://www.google.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(q);})(); ">Искать выделенное</a>
```

Как мне сделать то же самое, только уже мы вставляем выделенный текст в поле на моем сайте ? Под `"id = 77"`.

Comment: не понятно. Вы хотите, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку/кнопку выделенный текст копировался в поле на Вашем сайте? или иное?

Comment: да, 
Во время копирования информации я нахожусь на одном сайте 
А вставляется он уже на мой сайт